# Makefile and variable target from command line

Tags: variables, makefile

Newbie question for Makefiles... why doesn't this work?

```
TARGET=$@

$(TARGET): * **/*
    @echo "TARGET=$(TARGET)"
```

Where this does?

```
TARGET=my_target

$(TARGET): * **/*
    @echo "TARGET=$(TARGET)"
```

When started with `make my_target`?

Result of the former is, "no rule to make target `my_target'."

In addition to the question "why this doesn't work," is there a workaround? I'd like to be able to specify an arbitrary target from the command line. I suppose I could react to an env var, but that makes the CLI clunky, e.g., `make target=my_target build` or similar.

I've searched, but I'm not getting the right hits to solve this. GNU make 3.81. Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The automatic variable `$@` is defined in the context of a pattern rule; outside of any rule it has no value.

If you want Make to do the same thing to *whatever target you name,* you can use a match-anything rule:

```
%:
    @echo TARGET=$@
```

Comment: That seems to make sense, but if I do `GIVEN = $@` in the main body, it _does_ get assigned; I can echo it in my target. In any case, using `%:` is dropping my dependencies, and then, of course, it's capturing everything. I didn't state it in my question, but I would like to capture specific targets such as `clean`, and `%:` doesn't seem to be allowing that.

Comment: That's because by using `=` you are creating a variable containing the literal string `$@`.  Then this value is expanded when you _use_ the variable `$(GIVEN)`, in the context where you use it, not the context where the variable is assigned.  See https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/html_node/Reading-Makefiles.html for a description of when variable values are evaluated.